# Find the differential equation of the system of plane curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given:
$${\left(x-c_1\right)}^2+c_2y=c_3\tag1$$
Since there are three arbitrary constants, I could tell that the differential equation will have an order of 3. Thus, by differentiating both sides of the equation three times, I get
$$2\left(x-c_1\right)+c_2y^\prime=0\tag2$$
$$2+c_2y^{\prime\prime}=0\tag3$$
$$c_2y^{\prime\prime\prime}=0\tag4$$
I could guess that I won't be using Eq. (1) in find the DE because of $c_3$. I noticed that I could rewrite Eq. (3) as $c_2y^{\prime\prime}=-2$ then divide Eq. (4) by this rewritten equation. Thus,
$$\frac{c_2y^{\prime\prime\prime}}{c_2y^{\prime\prime}}=\frac{0}{-2}\tag5$$
Therefore, the differential equation is
$$\frac{y^{\prime\prime\prime}}{y^{\prime\prime}}=0\tag6$$
What I'd like to know is if this is a valid differential equation (I know that $y^{\prime\prime\prime}=0$, so Eq. (6) would automatically be $0$) to the given solution and if there are other possible differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't need to differentiate more than once. Your second equation is already a differential equation. Unless of course you want to eliminate all parameters.

Comment: My goal was to eliminate all three arbitrary constants as that was the instruction given to me. What do you suggest?

Comment: @J.Herrera Oh, you didn't say that before. In that case first eliminate $c_2$ between (2) and (3) before differentiating the third time to get rid of $c_1.$ (You'd have to use the quotient rule here).

Comment: @J.Herrera In any case your result $y'''=0$ is good enough, since if you integrate thrice you get back a family of parabolas.

Comment: So what I could also do is solve for $c_2$ using $\left(3\right)$ then plug it back into $\left(2\right)$ for a different DE, correct?

Comment: @J.Herrera That's also a way. But it adds little to what you already did.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much!